# How can I transfer file from SFTP using python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp

I would like to use paramiko for SFTP file transfer in Python 3.6. I know that paramiko depends on PyCrypto and have read about PyCrypto installation problems in Python 3.6. Although I have seen a number of questions regarding this topic, I have not found a solution to successful SFTP file transfer in Python 3.6.

My first question: is it possible to use Python 3.6 for SFTP file transfer? If so, will paramiko work? If the above will work, why I am I receiving the following errors when attempting to install PyCrypto?

```
error: [WinError 2] The system canot find the file specified
**Failed building wheel for pycrypto**
```

My second question: if paramiko will not work with Python 3.6, are there any alternatives or must I revert back to a previous python version for SFTP file transfer?

Comment: error: [WinError 2] The system canot find the file specified
**Failed building wheel for pycrypto**

Comment: your problem is that being on windows (WinError) you have to go through some hoops like installing vc to compile some packages like here (look for installing pycrypto on windows). You could try using conda/anaconda that will help as it install most of the tools needed, or find the wheel already package for your windows environment on google.

Comment: cannot install directly because the proxy is blocking it

Comment: That's rather unusual constraint. You should mention it in in your question! -- Did you you try configuring the proxy in pip?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to the configured proxy. But, that didn't work.

Comment: *"didn't work"* doesn't work as a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Yes through python can possible to file transfer with sftp. Python has a nice package

**Step 1 :**

```
pip install pysftp
```

**Step 2:**

Example how to transfer file:

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public'):             # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
        sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```